# RSA encryption/decryption method

Tags: encryption, methods, cryptography, rsa

i've seen this interesting method to encrypt/decrypt messages with RSA on YouTube and it works, I've tested it  : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tXXnHXslVhw&t=98s minute 1:45 . I am not that good at math, is there a name for what this guy is doing?

```
void En() {
 crypted= text;
 unsigned long long temp=0;
 unsigned long long enc = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < text.length() / 2; i++)
 {
   if (text[i]>='a' && text[i] <= 'z')
   {
    temp = (text[i] - 96) * 26 + text[i + 1] - 96;
    enc = pow(temp, public_key);
    enc= enc % N
    cout << enc << endl;
    enc_v2 = enc;
   }

 }

cout << "Enc: " << enc << endl;}


void De() {
 unsigned long long temp2 = 0;
 unsigned long long temp = 0;
 char ch=' ', ch2=' ';
 for (int i = 0; i < text.length()/2; i++)
{
  cout << enc_v2 << private_key;
  temp = pow(enc_v2, private_key);
  cout << "Temp :" << temp;
  temp = temp % N;
  cout << "Temp modulo :" << temp;
  temp2 = temp;
  temp = temp / 26;
  cout << " Temp char 1 :"<< temp;
  ch = temp + 96;


   temp2 = temp2 - temp * 26;
   cout << " Temp char 1 :" << temp2;
   ch2 = temp2 + 96;
}
cout << "Text: " << ch << ch2;}
```

P.S. I know about the pow and modular exponentiation , this in only to show what he is doing.
Thank you!

Comment: He is describing the radix-B representation of a message, where B is the size of the alphabet (or character set) in each position of a message. For example, if the message is composed solely of letters then B=26. If the message is an array of bytes then B=256. However, depending on the size of the modulus it may be more efficient to to group multiple bytes together into a block. In that case B=256\*\*k, where k is the number of bytes in a block. The important rule is B *must* be less than the modulus.

Comment: This is fine for educational toys, but for real encryption applications RSA needs a padding scheme like OAEP, or even simpler a scheme like KEM. RSA is not used to directly encrypt data, instead it is used in a hybrid encryption scheme where an (e.g.) AES key K is encapsulated with RSA and the data is encrypted with AES using key K.

Comment: Converting from radix-X to radix-Y is is simply called base conversion, by the way. So e.g. radix-256 to radix-65536.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! I will seek more info about it.